# Where do I start to troubleshoot this strange activity from my firewall?

Tags: networking, firewall, port, malware, tcp

I noticed that my firewall yesterday blocked outgoing attempts starting at port 61494 and worked its way up to 62381, making a TCP outgoing attempt at each port once. The remote IP address seems random, and changed up every 1-20 times. The remote port is always port80.  Here is a small snippet below.

Is this a trojan? How do I begin to troubleshoot this to figure out whats going?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It *could be* malware, or it could be an attempted Torrent connection or something else. The first few IP addresses resolve to *cdn1.static.pornhub.phncdn.com.swiftcdn1.com*.

You can find out what program is sending these requests with [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/) for Windows or [BitMeter OS](http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeterOs) for linux, mac and Windows.

Comment: glasswire, never heard of it, what a fantastic little app. Still can't figure this out, I had another wave of outgoing TCP packets 1 port at a time going up in the 60000 range again tonight.This time port 443 was involved.The sites I saw them resolve to vary from what you said to apple, google, dropbox, etc??